# Showing a dynamic number of views in RecyclerView item?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to re-create this:

[image]

I have a list of data:

```
List<Block> blocks;
```

And the `Block.java` class has a method `getNumBlocks()` which returns the number of blocks that item should show. The number of blocks can range from something as small as 1 block to something as large as 20 blocks.

I created a normal RecyclerView adapter, along with the `ImageView` layout for the block:

```
public class BlockAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlockAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    private List<Block> blocks;

    public BlockAdapter(Context context, List<Block> blocks) {
        this.context = context;
        this.blocks = blocks;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView block;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            block = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.block);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BlockAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.block_layout, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Block block = blocks.get(position);

        // How to use block.getNumBlocks() to show the correct number of blocks?
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blocks.size();
    }

}
```

Here is `block_layout.xml` (it's just an empty LinearLayout, the blocks should be added inside of this LinearLayout):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/card_bg"
    android:padding="16dp">


</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the `block.xml` layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/block"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
```

So my question is, how can I implement this so that it shows the correct number of blocks for each RecyclerView item?

What is the best way to do this **performance wise**?

Comment: from your block object get the desired number of blocks and add your imageview dynamically into your linear layout

Comment: @Gautam How is that done? What about performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's good that you care about performance. Creating new `ImageViews` every time you want to display a row is against the idea of recycling views. Basically when scrolling you would re-use only the top level views, but still creating new `ImageViews` for any item every time it appears on screen.

To deal with that you can create your own pool of views like that:

```
public class BlockAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BlockAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Block> blocks;
    private final List<ImageView> imageViewPool = new LinkedList<>();

    public BlockAdapter(List<Block> blocks) {
        this.blocks = blocks;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return blocks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public BlockAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.block_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(blocks.get(position));
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final List<ImageView> imageViews = new ArrayList<>();
        private final ViewGroup container;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            container = (ViewGroup) itemView;
        }

        public void bind(Block block) {
            recycleImageViews();
            for (int i = 0; i < block.getNumBlocks(); ++i) {
                final ImageView imageView = getRecycledImageViewOrCreate();
                imageViews.add(imageView);
                container.addView(imageView);
            }
        }

        private ImageView getRecycledImageViewOrCreate() {
            if (imageViewPool.isEmpty()) {
                return (ImageView)LayoutInflater.from(container.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.block, container, false);
            }
            return imageViewPool.remove(0);
        }

        public void recycleImageViews() {
            imageViewPool.addAll(imageViews);
            imageViews.clear();
            container.removeAllViews();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        holder.recycleImageViews();
    }
}
```

The idea behind this solution is very similar to what `RecyclerView` does.

Every time `ViewHolder` wants to present sub items it will:

- Take ImageView from the `imageViewPool`. If there is no spare one in the pool, a new one will be inflated.
- Attach this `ImageView` to itself.

Later, when particular `ViewHolder` is re-used or recycled it will:

- Detach all `ImageViews` from itself.
- Return those `ImageViews` to re-usable pool so next item that will appear on the screen can take those.

Comment: What is `SubBlock`?

Comment: You tell me... :) You haven't specified what items are stored inside the `Block` so I assumed that there is a list of some sub items, called them `SubBlock`, just for demonstrating purpose. Maybe in your case Blocks stores a list of Strings, maybe something else. You must have some list inside `Block` that will be represented by those `ImageViews`

Comment: All that is in `Block` class is `getNumBlocks()` which returns the number of blocks to show, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

Comment: So your blocks are indistinguishable and you just want to display particular amount of them (represented by value returned from `getNumBlocks()`), right? I've updated the code to just get certain amount of them from the pool and display in a row.

Answer (score 0):

First change your viewholader and get the reference of your root layout -

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout root;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        root = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.root);
    }
}
```

After that inside bindview holder iterate over a loop with size of blocks

```
for(int i=0;i<block.size;i++) {
        ImageView blockImg = new ImageView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
        blockImg.setLayoutParams(lp);
        holder.root.addView(blockImg);
    }
```

Using LayoutParams you can give desired margin as well and apply it over imageview

Comment: it wont have any significant effect on performance as your views will be recycled . Plus if your number of blocks are not fixed then you have to add them dynamically.

Comment: but if there is anything inside the "block" that needs to be dynamically set, say a textview, or imageview that changes with recyclerview positions, this will fail...  the onbind method won't be able to locate the views...